# How to add child linear layout in android project

Tags: android-layout

Here is my XML file code I want to add 3 child linear layout to its parent layout how to do it

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llTopMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    >

    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:background= "#F778A1"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout android:layout_above="@+id/llBottomMain"
    android:layout_below="@id/llTopMain"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llMidMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llMidMainExt1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    >


    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:background= "#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    />


    </LinearLayout>

    ***<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llMidMainExt2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    >***


    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:background= "#0F0F0F"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    />


    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llBottomMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:background= "#F778A1"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

 </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I cannot add android:id="@+id/llMidMainExt2" to its parent layout How to solve this? Thanks in advance.